# mongodb aggregation lookup with multiple conditions and ids

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

Having the following collections and data on them

```
db.a.insert([
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb00105e8f41"), "items" : [{id:ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb00105e8f41"), "instock" : 120}]},
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb00105e8f42"), "items" : [{id:ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb00105e8f42"), "instock" : 120}] },
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb00105e8f43"), "items" : [{ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb00105e8f43"), "instock" : 80}] }
])

db.b.insert([
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb00105e8f41")},
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb00105e8f42")},
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb00105e8f43")},
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb00105e8f44")},
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb00105e8f45")}
])
```

executing an lookup aggregation like

```
db.b.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "b",
           let: { bId: "$_id", qty: 100 },
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$items.id",  "$$bId" ] },
                         { $gte: [ "$instock", "$$qty" ] }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              }
           ],
           as: "a"
         }
    }
])
```

does not bring any results in the expected lookup operation. Is there any restriction to use ObjectId as a comparison? In the official documentations does not say any about it and it works like a charm with any other kind of data type, like strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a bug in mongodb or not but the query only works after adding an `$unwind` stage first.

```
db.b.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "a",
           let: { bId: "$_id", qty: 100 },
           pipeline: [
           {    
             $unwind: {
               path: "$items"
             }
           },
           { $match:
              { $expr:
                        { $and:
                            [
                                { $eq: [ "$items.id",  "$$bId" ] },
                                { $gte: [ "$items.instock",  "$$qty" ] },
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
           ],
           as: "a"
         }
    }
]);
```

Note: [Join Conditions and Uncorrelated Sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) were added in mongo 3.6

Comment: thanks @abdelrahman-hossam any advice on how to debug an aggregation? be able to trace or something? thanks

Comment: @bitgandtter mongodb compass can be helpful with that. sometimes If I am getting unexpected results I try to remove stages from the end or remove parts of the query. like in your case when I commented `{ $eq: [ "$items.id",  "$$bId" ] }` I was getting the expected result that's what made me try unwinding first.